# paypal payment pending and completed transaction(same ones) have different tx_ids

Tags: javascript, paypal, transactions, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal and paypal webhooks. When payment takes place in client-side, I get notifications about it on my back-end.

Turns out, I get 2 notifications for the same payment. One that has status as `PENDING` and other one that has status as `COMPLETED`. Even though they are the details of the same payment, their id's are different. Why is that?

I am asking because, I want to store all transactions pending, completed, denied into my database. I need something unique so that I can update the status of the transaction. If the same payment has different id-s, how can I update from PENDING to COMPLETED in my database?

**PAYMENT.CAPTURE.PENDING WEBHOOK DATA**

```
{
    "id": "WH-05T33772A52658430-32J33305NG495525W",
    "create_time": "2019-08-06T07:25:05.456Z",
    "resource_type": "capture",
    "event_type": "PAYMENT.CAPTURE.PENDING",
    "summary": "Payment pending for EUR 1.0 EUR",
    "resource": {
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        "seller_protection": {
            "status": "ELIGIBLE",
            "dispute_categories": [
                "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
            ]
        },
        "update_time": "2019-08-06T07:25:00Z",
        "create_time": "2019-08-06T07:25:00Z",
        "final_capture": true,
        "invoice_id": "6,7,1565076281554.6213",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/2W106091AH697743F",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/2W106091AH697743F/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/0JA94285K3916615D",
                "rel": "up",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "id": "2W106091AH697743F",
        "status_details": {
            "reason": "RECEIVING_PREFERENCE_MANDATES_MANUAL_ACTION"
        },
        "status": "PENDING"
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "transmissions": [
        {
            "webhook_url": "https://giorgilagidze.com/api/payments/paypal/ipn",
            "response_headers": {
                "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
                "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
                "X-RateLimit-Remaining": "56",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache, private",
                "Server": "nginx/1.15.8",
                "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
                "X-RateLimit-Limit": "60",
                "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
                "Date": "Tue, 06 Aug 2019 07:26:16 GMT",
                "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            "transmission_id": "521fe300-b81b-11e9-bdaa-7b0f83d3d8cf",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "timestamp": "2019-08-06T07:25:09Z"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-05T33772A52658430-32J33305NG495525W",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET",
            "encType": "application/json"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-05T33772A52658430-32J33305NG495525W/resend",
            "rel": "resend",
            "method": "POST",
            "encType": "application/json"
        }
    ],
    "event_version": "1.0",
    "resource_version": "2.0"
}
```

**CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED WEBHOOK DATA**

```
{
    "id": "WH-8L74536230699424S-3UL381024U924281P",
    "create_time": "2019-08-06T07:25:02.923Z",
    "resource_type": "checkout-order",
    "event_type": "CHECKOUT.ORDER.APPROVED",
    "summary": "An order has been approved by buyer",
    "resource": {
        "update_time": "2019-08-06T07:25:00Z",
        "create_time": "2019-08-06T07:24:43Z",
        "purchase_units": [
            {
                "reference_id": "default",
                "amount": {
                    "currency_code": "EUR",
                    "value": "1.00"
                },
                "payee": {
                    "email_address": "gioskofield-facilitator@gmail.com",
                    "merchant_id": "M8FBTS3ZCRGCE"
                },
                "invoice_id": "6,7,1565076281554.6213",
                "shipping": {
                    "name": {
                        "full_name": "test buyer"
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "address_line_1": "1 Main St",
                        "admin_area_2": "San Jose",
                        "admin_area_1": "CA",
                        "postal_code": "95131",
                        "country_code": "US"
                    }
                },
                "payments": {
                    "captures": [
                        {
                            "id": "2W106091AH697743F",
                            "status": "PENDING",
                            "status_details": {
                                "reason": "RECEIVING_PREFERENCE_MANDATES_MANUAL_ACTION"
                            },
                            "amount": {
                                "currency_code": "EUR",
                                "value": "1.00"
                            },
                            "final_capture": true,
                            "seller_protection": {
                                "status": "ELIGIBLE",
                                "dispute_categories": [
                                    "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                                    "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
                                ]
                            },
                            "invoice_id": "6,7,1565076281554.6213",
                            "links": [
                                {
                                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/2W106091AH697743F",
                                    "rel": "self",
                                    "method": "GET"
                                },
                                {
                                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/2W106091AH697743F/refund",
                                    "rel": "refund",
                                    "method": "POST"
                                },
                                {
                                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/0JA94285K3916615D",
                                    "rel": "up",
                                    "method": "GET"
                                }
                            ],
                            "create_time": "2019-08-06T07:25:00Z",
                            "update_time": "2019-08-06T07:25:00Z"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/0JA94285K3916615D",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "id": "0JA94285K3916615D",
        "intent": "CAPTURE",
        "payer": {
            "name": {
                "given_name": "test",
                "surname": "buyer"
            },
            "email_address": "gioskofield-buyer@gmail.com",
            "payer_id": "UCCQBA8S6GUR4",
            "address": {
                "country_code": "US"
            }
        },
        "status": "COMPLETED"
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "transmissions": [
        {
            "webhook_url": "https://giorgilagidze.com/api/payments/paypal/ipn",
            "response_headers": {
                "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
                "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
                "X-RateLimit-Remaining": "60",
                "Cache-Control": "no-cache, private",
                "Server": "nginx/1.15.8",
                "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
                "X-RateLimit-Limit": "60",
                "X-XSS-Protection": "1; mode=block",
                "Date": "Tue, 06 Aug 2019 07:26:17 GMT",
                "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
            },
            "transmission_id": "503d1940-b81b-11e9-bdaa-7b0f83d3d8cf",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "timestamp": "2019-08-06T07:25:06Z"
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-8L74536230699424S-3UL381024U924281P",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET",
            "encType": "application/json"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-8L74536230699424S-3UL381024U924281P/resend",
            "rel": "resend",
            "method": "POST",
            "encType": "application/json"
        }
    ],
    "event_version": "1.0",
    "resource_version": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the transaction ID you're looking at and not the Correlation ID?  Can you provide a copy of the webhook data you're getting?

Comment: When I received payment.capture.completed, resource.id looks like to be the capture id.  and the only way to figure out order id is to look into resource.links and find the link that says  /checkout/orders/id and take the last parameter after last slash. Is this correct?

Comment: Hey Drew. Could you take a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57381603/is-storing-order-id-via-paypal-payment-really-necessary . basically i explained it better. No one answers paypal related question. Just try . I'd appreciate it .