# is storing order_id via paypal payment really necessary?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using paypal gateway. I am using js sdk smart payment buttons.

**Question 1)** Turns out that when I make a payment through js, it returns me id and capture_id(id means `order_id` and `capture_id` means `transaction_id`). Then I use `webhooks` to catch events on my back-end. Looks like it takes me lots of parsing 'links' property in it to get order_id. **Is it really necessary to have order_id stored in my db? or capture id is enough to do anything?**

**Question 2)** when events arrive on my back-end, sometimes they arrive 2 times or 3 times. (Same events). Why is that? I acknowledge receiving them via `return response('', 200);` but still, this is not enough. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Depends entirely on your implementation. Is there something wrong (in your implementation) that prevents webhooks from working for you?


2. Webhooks are asynchronous, their order is not guaranteed, and idempotency might lead to a duplicate notification of the same event type.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/?mark=webhooks#overview

Comment: 1) when webhooks come, the only way to grab order_id from it is to take resource.links which is an array of hrefs and find the one that has /checkout/orders substring in it and grab the last parameter of that href which turns out to be order_id. That's what I hate to do. 2) so it's possible for same event to appear multiple times. am I doing the right thing when I have return response('', 200) at the end of the webhook listener function?

Comment: 1. Sounds like just a matter of your preference? Otherwise I think you'd have to start your project all over. 2. Without seeing anything else of your code, there's no way to tell beyond what the documentation states. Which language are you writing?  Are you using the webhooks sdk or diy? See, too much to guess here.

Comment: 1) what does it have to do to my implementation? webhook doesn't have stored order_id directly unless i use that hack i said.

Comment: Sounds like you just answered your own question.  :)